How do I create IOT device shadow using AWS CLI?
According to this, you can create a device shadow using an UPDATE command. That would explain why the aws iot-data cli commands do not have a create-device-shadow command. However, I'm unable to use the update-device-shadow command to create the device. If I run this:
aws iot-data update-thing-shadow --thing-name mydevice --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"state": {"reported": {"generated": 0}}}' "output.txt"
I get an error saying that:

An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the
UpdateThingShadow operation: Payload contains invalid json

What am I doing wrong?
I'm running this from a PowerShell terminal.

FWIW, I'm doing exactly the same thing from a Linux terminal (only my payload is different) and it works for me.
